# Show a sentence with animation

Tags: html, css

I would like to show a sentence with animation like [this site](http://www.criteo.com/) (Where state-of-the-art machine learning means more sales.).

The html body is as follows. It seems that it may change:

```
Where state-of-the-art machine learning means more
<span class="js-animate-words" style="width: 281px; height: 64px; display: inline-block;">
  <span class="js-animate-words__label js-animate-words__label--in">sales.</span>
  <span class="js-animate-words__label">discovery.</span>
  <span class="js-animate-words__label">relevance.</span>
</span>
```

The CSS is:

```
.js-animate-words {
  position:relative;
}
.js-animate-words__label--in {
  opacity:1;
  transform:scale(1);
}
.js-animate-words__label--out {
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0.8);
}
.js-animate-words__label {
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  transform:scale(1.2);
  transition:all 0.8s ease;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

However, I cannot find what JavaScript library they use. Therefore, the 
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kameheg/4/edit?html,css,output) does not work.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Additionally, what if I want to reserve **the same length** for the words that change? For instance, I want to show

```
(sometimes:)
Where state-of-the-art machine learning means more sales.
(sometimes:)
Where state-of-the-art   data mining    means more sales.
```

Comment: A cursory examination of that links code shows they are using jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: I added jquery and bootstrap, it still does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in their app.min.js where they are doing the class-changing. It looks like they are doing some simple width/height calculations, with a `setTimeout` function. Here is the code that handles that:

```
$(function() {
    var t, e, o = $(".js-animate-words"), n = 0, i = 3500, s = function() {
        var e = 0
          , n = 0;
        t.each(function() {
            var t = $(this);
            t.width() > e && (e = t.width()),
            t.outerHeight() > n && (n = t.outerHeight())
        }),
        o.css({
            width: e,
            height: n
        });
        var i = o.offset()
          , s = $(window).width() - 20
          , r = i.left + e;
        r > s ? o.css({
            display: "block"
        }) : o.css({
            display: "inline-block"
        }),
        o.parent("h1").css({
            position: "relative",
            top: "1px"
        }),
        setTimeout(function() {
            o.parent("h1").css({
                position: "relative",
                top: ""
            })
        }, 1e3)
    }
    , r = function() {
        t.removeClass("js-animate-words__label--in"),
        t.eq(n).addClass("js-animate-words__label--in"),
        "" !== e && t.eq(e).addClass("js-animate-words__label--out"),
        setTimeout(function() {
            n < t.length - 1 ? n++ : n = 0,
            e = n - 1 >= 0 ? n - 1 : t.length - 1,
            r()
        }, i)
    }
    , a = function() {
        for (var e = o.text().split(","), n = e.length, i = "", a = 0; n > a; a++)
            i += '<span class="js-animate-words__label">' + e[a].trim() + "</span>";
        o.html(i),
        t = $(".js-animate-words__label"),
        t.on("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(t) {
            $(this).hasClass("js-animate-words__label--out") && $(this).removeClass("js-animate-words__label--out")
        }),
        s(),
        $(window).on("resize", s),
        r()
    }
    ;
    o.length && a()
})
```

Comment: Why can I only see [this code](https://s4.postimg.org/p8hqv9p59/Screen_Shot_2016_08_15_at_04_51_47.png) for `app.min.js`? Could you make a JSBin work?

Comment: Try using Chrome DevTools to inspect the page.. [this is how i found it](http://recordit.co/0X2EEHzbSB)